# How to make table view inside a container view to not bounce on keyboard popup?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have static table view controller in which one cell is a container view which has another table view which dynamic. The inner table view has a text field and when on tap, the keyboard pops up. In the main (outer) table view controller, I have the below function to update the constraint on keyboard show.

```
func updateConstraints() {
    let bottom: CGFloat = 0
    if let popup = self.addItemPopupView {
        self.popupBottomContraints?.isActive = false
        if self.isKeyboardActive {
            self.popupBottomContraints = popup.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                                                       constant: -self.keyboardHeight+bottom)
        } else {
            self.popupBottomContraints = popup.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.toolbar.topAnchor, constant: bottom)
        }
        self.popupBottomContraints?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

But the problem is that on keyboard display, the inner table view jumps to the top inside the container view while the main view controller itself moves to the top. How to prevent the inner table view to not move at all? I have disabled scroll, bounce for the table view, but it still happens.

---

The outer table cell has dynamic height set to the inner table view's content height so there is no need for scroll.

[See the video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r2YYAuaSRYcB1cFsLxZmWITuNWRvNZaj)

Comment: what is the behaviour of  inner tableview, in case of keyboard dismiss?

Comment: On keyboard dismiss, there is no issue, no jumping around. The main view just slides downward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the container view and using the table view directly in the main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

did some modification in your code

```
**replace** self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor **to** self.toolbar.topAnchor. 


func updateConstraints() {
    let bottom: CGFloat = 0
    if let popup = self.addItemPopupView {
        self.popupBottomContraints?.isActive = false
        if self.isKeyboardActive {
            self.popupBottomContraints = popup.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.toolbar.topAnchor,
                                                                       constant: -self.keyboardHeight+bottom)
        } else {
            self.popupBottomContraints = popup.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.toolbar.topAnchor, constant: bottom)
        }
        self.popupBottomContraints?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: just comment updateConstraints method and then run and then let me know behaviour of innerTable view

Comment: I tried, it's the same issue. I attached the video recording to the question, with constraints enabled.

Comment: issue is not in the updateConstraints, it is in your inner tableView.

Comment: what you did when user click on textfield ?

Comment: I have `func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.isHeaderEditing = true;
        self.tableView.reloadData();
    }` as the delegate method.

Comment: why  self.tableView.reloadData()?, just comment this line and run again othereise use tableView.beginUpdate and tableView.endUpdate method if you required.

Comment: Sorry, that's the wrong delegate I posted. I am not doing anything on text field tap. The other one posted above was when tapping on the checklist header.